# Add jQuery UI events to meteor template

Tags: jquery-ui, events, meteor

I am starting an app using meteor.js and I would like to know if there is a way to add jquery events to a meteor template.

Here I will take the example of the slider widget from Jquery UI.

So far my code is this :

```
Template.price_selector.rendered = function (){
  $( "#price_selector" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    values: [ 0, 200 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - €" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }
  });

};
```

But I would like (and I think the right way to do is) to be able to bind the event like I do for a click on a button for instance like so :

```
Template.price_selector.events({
  'slide #price_selector': function(event, ui){
    $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - €" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
  }
});
```

Do you know if there is some way for doing this ?

Otherwise, where can I find a list of the supported event in meteor ?

Comment: https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/window.resize.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to integrate custom events like that into Meteor's events method. There's actually nothing wrong with your code. The only thing I'd add is a check to make sure the plugin hasn't already been initialized. So:

```
Template.price_selector.rendered = function (){

    if (! $('#price_selector').data('uiSlider')) {
        // The data attribute for the slider is not set, so the slider has not yet been created
        // If the slider is still around, we don't want to initialize it again
        $( "#price_selector" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
            values: [ 0, 200 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - €" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
    }

};
```

According to the jQuery UI wiki, plugin instances are accessible via `$( "#something" ).data( "pluginname" )`, so you can use that to check if a plugin's already initialized.

Note that a lot of this will change with the upcoming Meteor UI update, so stay tuned for a better way to do things like this within the next couple of months.

EDIT: for a list of available events, check out the [Event Maps section in the Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps), and the list is at the end of that section, with explanations of each event. For convenience though, they are: `click`, `dblclick`, `focus`, `blur`, `change`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `keydown`, `keypress`, `keyup`, `tap`. Note that there are other events as well, but the dev team has tried to make these ones work smoothly cross-browser/device.

Comment: This was [originally answered on CodersClan](http://www.codersclan.net/ticket/79)